# How can I insert data into an xml file

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xml, xslt

I am trying to create a simple html form that inserts data into an xml file.  I would like the files to be stored on a cloud server like google drive.  I would like the page to use jquery and possibly AJAX if necessary.  The form should be an xsl style sheet (seperate file would be nice).  My main concern is how to insert the data into the xml file.  I am looking for some tips and if someone could simply create a sample so I can see what should be done.  I would like to avoid a database if possible.

Here is a sample xml of the data I need to insert.  Thanks for all the help!!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <record>
        <Timestamp>01/01/2015</Timestamp>
        <Acceptance1>Y</Acceptance1>
        <Acceptance2>Y</Acceptance2>
        <Fname>Tom</Fname>
        <Lname>Smith</Lname>
        <Address>123 Smith Avenue</Address>
        <City>Nowhere</City>
        <State>CA</State>
        <Zip>90210</Zip>
        <Email>abc@yahoo.com</Email>
        <Phone>1234564561</Phone>
        <Date>01/01/2015</Date>
        <MemberAgreement>Y</MemberAgreement>
        <Acceptance3>Y</Acceptance3>
        <LibraryPolicy>Y</LibraryPolicy>
        <Acceptance4>Y</Acceptance4>
        <LendingLibrary>Y</LendingLibrary>
        <PaymentType>Check</PaymentType>
    </record>
</data-set>
```

Comment: I am looking for advice and a possible solution.  Any help here?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
$(xml).find("data-set").find("record").append("<SecondName>Vardens</SecondName>");
```

Comment: Yes, but how does the page know what the data set is.  What is the ajax that brings the xml file into the page?